# What is extraction?

Tags: syntax

Chapter 1 of *Parasitic Gaps*, edited by Culicover and Postal, begins with this example:

> Which articles did John file *t* without reading *pg*?

The italicized *t* is reported to be a "true gap" because it is in a position that normally permits "extraction", and this example is given: Which articles did John file *t*?, and *pg* is a "parasitic gap" because it appears in a location that does not normally permit extraction.

What is "extraction"?

Answer (score 3):

In the below sentence:

> 1. the dog that Jake patted *t*

The constituent "the dog" is said to be extracted from the embedded clause "that Jake patted *t*", and is coreferent to a *gap* that is in the object position of the verb "patted". That's all that extraction is -- a relative clause ("the dog that Jake patted") headed by a noun ("the dog") which is coreferent to a gap within the embedded clause (the object of "patted").

Knowing this, what does it mean that "it appears in a location that does not normally permit extraction"?

This means that the inside of the preposition "without" is not usually a position from which extraction is possible. This can be seen as follows:

> 2. Without imagining the book, I couldn't read it.
> 3. *the book that without imagining, I couldn't read *t*

However, it *is* licensed by the parasitic gap construction, suggesting that extraction gaps are different to parasitic gaps.

> 4. That's the book that I can't read *t* without imagining *pg*.

Comment: "the book that I couldn't read without imagining" seems perfectly normal. "the book that without imagining, I couldn't read" is just a bit odd by comparison.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Note that you could insert "it" after "imagining" but not "read", suggesting simple ellipsis rather than extraction.

Comment: @LukeSawczak : Probably your comment is immediately comprehensible to those familiar with this kind of theory of syntax. Can you elaborate for those who are not?